# What does %f represent in the git clean/smudge filters

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

Inside my `~/.gitconfig` file I see that there is the following lfs filter:

```
[filter "lfs"]
        clean = git-lfs clean -- %f
        smudge = git-lfs smudge -- %f
        process = git-lfs filter-process
        required = true
```

**Question**: What does `%f` represent in the lfs filter? My understanding is it represents the file path but I'm not sure what file path it represents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [`.gitattributes` "`filter`" section](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_filter), it is presented as:

> Sequence "`%f`" on the filter command line is replaced with the name of the file the filter is working on.
> A filter might use this in keyword substitution. For example:
>
> ```yaml
> [filter "p4"]
>   clean = git-p4-filter --clean %f
>   smudge = git-p4-filter --smudge %f
> ```
>
> Note that "`%f`" is the name of the path that is being worked on.
> Depending on the version that is being filtered, the corresponding file on disk may not exist, or may have different contents.
>
> So, `smudge` and `clean` commands should not try to access the file on disk, but only act as filters on the content provided to them on standard input.